# Delphi REST library обновить Access Token google api

Tags: delphi, rest, oauth2, google-drive

У меня вопрос по работе с сетью в Delphi

С помощью REST library (с которой знаком поверхностно) подключаюсь к Google drive api

в OAuth2Authenticator-е успешно получил Access и Refresh token-ы

пытаюсь обновить AccesToken так

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
LToken :string;
begin
RESTClient1.BaseURL:='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
try
  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;


  RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('grant_type', 'refresh_token', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('refresh_token', OAuth2Authenticator1.RefreshToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('client_id',OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientID,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('client_secret',OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientSecret,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);

  RESTRequest1.Execute;


  if RESTRequest1.Response.GetSimpleValue('access_token', LToken) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(LToken);
    OAuth2Authenticator1.AccessToken := LToken;
  end;

  if RESTRequest1.Response.GetSimpleValue('refresh_token', LToken) then
  begin
    OAuth2Authenticator1.RefreshToken := LToken;
  end;

finally
  RESTClient1.DisposeOf;
end;
end;
```

получаю исключение

> ETHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 404 not found'

Видимо неправильно составил запрос

Но параметры добавлял все те, которые указаны в документации google
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer
(Пункт Refreshing an access token (offline access))

Как правильно составить запрос?

Comment: С помощью idhttp сделать смог

Но с REST пока не получается

Comment: Решение с помощью idhttp:
http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=314260